# Hiding div's in a webpage using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have a div and that div contains text.

```
<div style='visibility:hidden;' id='emailid'>$email</div>
```

The visibility attribute does the job of hiding the text contained. The problem is it takes up space (as blank white space) in the webpage where the div contents are supposed to be displayed if it was not hidden;

How can I prevent this from happening? How can I make the div not to show any blank space as the code above does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use `display:none;` in your CSS code for hiding a div completly from your displayed page.

Your CSS line of code will change to,

```
<div style='display:none;' id='emailid'>$email</div>
```

Using the `visibility:hidden;` will only prevent the div from being displayed on the page. It will still leave the space where the div would have been existed.

You can learn more about CSS display property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 3):

use `display:none;`

```
<div style='display:none;' id='emailid'>$email</div>
```

See the [The display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display: none;` to hide and set `display: block;` to show.

If you are trying to hide the links using `visibility: hidden;` it means the tag would not be visible, but space will be allocated for it on the page.

Please post your code for more details if this doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks Shruti for the help

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy Coding!                                                                
If it helped you, could you accept it as answer,so that it helps others facing the same  issue.?

Comment: Sure thing. As per StackOverflow, I have to wait for few minutes to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.myclass {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> display:none will not be available in the page and does not occupy any space.
>
> visibility:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout.
>
> visibility:hidden preserve the space, whereas display:none doesn't preserve the space

```
<div style='display:none;' id='emailid'>$email</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#emailid{
  display:none;
 }
```

display:none means it will not take space

Answer (score 0):

use `display:none` css properties;